# Bootstrap 3: Vertically stack buttons after first one wraps?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a login page with social buttons using Font Awesome icons. On larger devices the buttons are displayed horizontally next to each other, but as I resize my screen the right-most button will wrap underneath the other two buttons when they get too wide for the column. I would like for the buttons to stack vertically and expand to fill the space of the column instead of having a misplaced button underneath. I've tried a method using media queries but it's a bit hacky and I'm afraid it won't be easy to maintain, so I scratched that idea.

Here's what I have so far:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">
    <div class="row">
      <button id="login" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
      <button id="facebook" class="btn btn-default"><span class="fa fa-facebook fa-lg"></span> Facebook Login</button>
      <button id="google" class="btn btn-default"><span class="fa fa-google fa-lg"></span> Google Login</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions on how to tackle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options.  In my opinion media queries would be the cleanest but here are the options:

1) Adding a media query and targeting a special class that you can add to just those buttons:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
    .loginBtns {
        width:100%;
        display:block;
        margin: 10px 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
        <div class="row">
          <button id="login" class="btn btn-default loginBtns">Login</button>
          <button id="facebook" class="btn btn-default loginBtns"><span class="fa fa-facebook fa-lg"></span>  Facebook Login</button>
          <button id="google" class="btn btn-default loginBtns"><span class="fa fa-google fa-lg"></span>  Google Login</button>
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

2) Duplicating the buttons and hiding one version on small screens while showing the other.  I'm not a big fan of duplicating code so I wouldn't recommend this option but if you don't like media queries it could be an option.

```css
.loginBtns2 {
  width:100%;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
 
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8 hidden-xs">
        <div class="row">
          <button id="login" class="btn btn-default loginBtns">Login</button>
          <button id="facebook" class="btn btn-default loginBtns"><span class="fa fa-facebook fa-lg"></span>  Facebook Login</button>
          <button id="google" class="btn btn-default loginBtns"><span class="fa fa-google fa-lg"></span>  Google Login</button>
        </div>    
    </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 visible-xs">
    <div class="row">
      <button id="login" class="btn btn-default loginBtns2">Login</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <button id="facebook" class="btn btn-default loginBtns2"><span class="fa fa-facebook fa-lg"></span>  Facebook Login</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <button id="google" class="btn btn-default loginBtns2"><span class="fa fa-google fa-lg"></span>  Google Login</button>
    </div>  
 </div>
```

Here is a working codepen with both options too:
https://codepen.io/egerrard/pen/woVEJW

Comment: Awesome, solution 1 works as needed! I had some combination of the two at one point but it was somewhat wacky and would have been head-scratcher if I came back to it later. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this helpful. but try this..

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center">
         <div class="col-md-6">
          <button id="login" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
          <button id="facebook" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="fa fa-facebook fa-lg"></span>  Facebook Login</button>
          <button id="google" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="fa fa-google fa-lg"></span>  Google Login</button>
        </div>   
    </div>
</div>
```